# validate the identity of the chain

Tags: transactions, block-producer, mainnet, security

as a non-block producer, how do I know I'm uploading a transaction to the true eos blockchain and not an impersonator? What methods exist to verify that? Example: websites use certificates.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chain ID for each chain that is unique.  You can retrieve this with the get info API/cleos call.

You also enter this if you're say loading a new network into scatter.

`cleos --url <API ENDPOINT HERE> get info`

`http://127.0.0.1:8888/v1/chain/get_info`

This is [the main net](http://eosnetworkmonitor.io/#api):

```
{
  "server_version": "2fc5d1cb",
  "chain_id": "aca376f206b8fc25a6ed44dbdc66547c36c6c33e3a119ffbeaef943642f0e906",
  "head_block_num": 35934160,
  "last_irreversible_block_num": 35933831,
  "last_irreversible_block_id": "02244e87d51eefbce234da2f8238e8df20aff331bc9c66081e3d7b702bb7f178",
  "head_block_id": "02244fd02601f1067306775c02c4ec4ae8fb796ad375af66cdaa86cc6dcc048d",
  "head_block_time": "2019-01-06T02:06:51.500",
  "head_block_producer": "cochainworld",
  "virtual_block_cpu_limit": 34468896,
  "virtual_block_net_limit": 1048576000,
  "block_cpu_limit": 176723,
  "block_net_limit": 1045864,
  "server_version_string": "mainnet-1.5.0-dirty"
}
```

Comment: so that's a digital signature? Who has the private key to sign?

Comment: @mar233 chain_id is just a hash value of `eosio::genesis_state`.